# How to automatically create a username combining two fields with jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made the following code:

```
var fname = "";
var lname = "";
var username = "";

$('#new-user-form input[name=fname]').on('keyup', function() {
    var fname = $('#new-user-form input[name=fname]').val().substring(0,1).toLowerCase();
    var username = fname + lname;
    $('#new-user-form input[name=username]').val(username);
});
$('#new-user-form input[name=lname]').on('keyup', function() {
    var lname = $('#new-user-form input[name=lname]').val().toLowerCase();
    var username = fname + lname;
    $('#new-user-form input[name=username]').val(username);
});
```

What I want is for the username field to be filled automatically with the first letter of the first name and all of the last name. It kinda works but for each field individually. If I type Mario in the fname field, the letter m appears in the username field but as soon I start typing into the lname field, the username field clears up and only the lowercase last name appears. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var a=1; (function(){var a=2; console.log(a);})(); console.log(a);` VS. `var a=1; (function(){a=2; console.log(a);})(); console.log(a);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're basically overriding the username. You have to read both the firstname and lastname when you edit either one of them. You could create a function and pass it as a callback.

```
function createUsername()  {
 var fname = $('#new-user-form input[name=fname]').val().substring(0,1).toLowerCase();

var lname = $('#new-user-form input[name=lname]').val().toLowerCase();
  var username = fname + lname;
 $('#new-user-form input[name=username]').val(username);
}

$('#new-user-form input[name=fname]').on('keyup', createUsername);
$('#new-user-form input[name=lname]').on('keyup', createUsername);
```

[Link to a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yfxoxeu/)

Comment: They are also declare `fname` inside `'#new-user-form input[name=fname]'` and same for `lname` in `'#new-user-form input[name=lname]'` (`var ...`) so it doesn't update the global variable (But your answer is correct anyway)

Answer (score 0):

So, my approach here is to generate as many words as possible using two words (in your own case may be firstName and lastName) and combining the with list of prefix and suffix that I listed.

You can increase the prefix and suffix to get more suggestions.
This current code gives you 33 suggestions.

```js
const generateUsername = (word1, word2) => {
  const suffix = ["2021", "21", "theGreat", "10"];
  const prefix = ["great", "good", "the", "brilliant"];

  let suggestions = [];
  suggestions.push(`${word1}${word2}`);
  suffix.forEach((word) => {
    suggestions.push(`${word1}${word}${word2}`);
    suggestions.push(`${word1}${word}`);
    suggestions.push(`${word2}${word}`);
    suggestions.push(`${word1}${word2}${word}`);
  });
  prefix.forEach((word) => {
    suggestions.push(`${word1}${word}${word2}`);
    suggestions.push(`${word}${word1}`);
    suggestions.push(`${word}${word2}`);
    suggestions.push(`${word1}${word}${word2}`);
  });

  return suggestions;
};
console.log('Suggestions',generateUsername('John','Doe'))
```